# JavaScript Timer Using SetInterval

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a timer using JavaScript. I have the code below, but the issue is I can't clear the intervals unless I declare them outside, but when I declare them at the beginning, they run without the button click. Any way I can fix that?

```
let btnTimer = document.querySelectorAll(".timerButton");
let totalTimer = document.getElementById("totalTimer");
let i = 0, j = 0, h = 0, k = 0;
let time = k.toString() + h + ":" + j + i;
totalTimer.innerText = time;


for (item of btnTimer) {
item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let btnTmr = e.target.innerText;
    if (btnTmr == "Start") {
        i = i++;
        let intervalI = setInterval(function(){
            time = k.toString() + h + ":" + j + i;
            totalTimer.innerText = time;
            if (i < 9) {
                i++;
            } else if (i = 9) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }, 1000);
        let intervalJ = setInterval(function(){
            time = k.toString() + h + ":" + j + i;
            totalTimer.innerText = time;
            if (j < 6) {
                j++;
            } else {
                j = 0;
            }
        }, 10000);
    } else if (btnTmr == "Pause") {
        clearInterval(intervalI);
        clearInterval(intervalJ);
    } else {
        time = "00:00"
        totalTimer.innerText = time;
        clearInterval(intervalI);
        clearInterval(intervalJ);
    }
})}
```

Comment: You can declare variables without setting them (e.g., `let intervalI;`), then set them later (e.g. `intervalI = setIterval(...`).

Comment: Worth metioning you can define global variables dynamically. Instead of declaring it as `let intervalI` you can add them globally by writing `window.intervalI = setInterval(...)` and clear it likewise: `clearInterval(window.intervalI)`

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would break the button event listeners out into separate functions.

```js
let btnStart = document.getElementById("start");
let btnPause = document.getElementById("pause");
let btnClear = document.getElementById("clear");
let totalTimer = document.getElementById("totalTimer");
let i = 0,
  j = 0,
  h = 0,
  k = 0;
let time = k.toString() + h + ":" + j + i;
let intervalI, intervalJ
totalTimer.innerText = time;

btnPause.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  clearInterval(intervalI);
  clearInterval(intervalJ);
})

btnClear.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  i = 0, j = 0
  time = "00:00"
  totalTimer.innerText = time;
  clearInterval(intervalI);
  clearInterval(intervalJ);
})

btnStart.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  i = i++;
  intervalI = setInterval(function() {
    time = k.toString() + h + ":" + j + i;
    totalTimer.innerText = time;
    if (i < 9) {
      i++;
    } else if (i == 9) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }, 500);

  intervalJ = setInterval(function() {
    time = k.toString() + h + ":" + j + i;
    totalTimer.innerText = time;
    if (j < 6) {
      j++;
    } else {
      j = 0;
    }
  }, 5000);
})
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
<div id="totalTimer"></div>
```